# How to align the the title and authors in the left column

Tags: titles

In the given two-column template, I am supposed to write the title and authors in the left column (and not centered across both columns).

Using some piece of latex code from some other question and answer, I was able to align the title and authors in the left column, but it also generated the following undesired artifacts:
- there are 3 footmarks at the end of the authors line (why are there 3 footmark when there are only two authors? Why is each footmark not displayed at the end of each author's name, but at the end of the line)?
- each footnote at the bottom of the left column is numerated (1,2,3). I did not want it to be numerated and therefore, the respective footnote numbers should not be displayed in the authors line.
- the author's line is written in the new line merely due to the length of the title line. If the title line were shorter, the authors line would start right next to it. How could I force a new line for the authors line?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside,shortpaper,9pt]{IEEEtran}  % IEEE class template


\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% a block of code that I found  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\argmin{\mathop{\rm arg\,min\,}}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\@title}
  \@author
  \@thanks
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%% end of code I found elsewhere %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Author~1\IEEEmembership{} and Author~2% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received...}%
\thanks{Author~1 is with...}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Author~2 is with...}}

\maketitle 
\begin{abstract}
    %\boldmath
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    some keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro text...

\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55
```

Now, could you provide me the portion of a code that would
- remove the footmarks
- print author names in the new line below the title

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  Or do you not want footnote marks at all?

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside,shortpaper,9pt]{IEEEtran}  % IEEE class template


\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% a block of code that I found  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\argmin{\mathop{\rm arg\,min\,}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\bfseries\large Some Title}\footnote{Manuscript received...}\\
{\large Author~1\IEEEmembership{}\footnote{Author~1 is with...} and Author~2\footnote{Author~2 is with...}}% <-this % stops a space
\end{center}




\begin{abstract}
    %\boldmath
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    some keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would like a slight modification of this solution: a) to keep the footnotes on the bottom, but not to label or enumerate any of them; (b) if I wanted to label the footnotes, how could I do it using number instead of the current symbols?

Comment: Ok, I got it after some additional research following your hint. Thanks!